# how to use aws application generated session stickiness in ELB

Tags: java, http, cookies, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have been struggling on this.

I implemented a very simple HTTP server on two EC2 instances behind an ELB. 
The HTTP server only reads the cookie from the header, and send back response with the same cookie in the response header.

At the client, I use

```
curl --cookie "mychannelid=mytest; Expires=Sat, 27-Jun-2017 02:48:17 GMT" --header "Accept-Language: en" "http://myelb.elb.amazonaws.com:8000/test"
```

Also, on the elb, I enabled application stickiness with cookie name mychannelid. But when I ran this system, I still got 50/50 server assignment. How can I implement this?

Another information is that, if generate the cookie at the HTTP server, and send back to the client, also, I need to access the HTTP server with firefox, then I can get what I want. If I access the HTTP server with curl, I can't. I don't know why, I checked the packets, the cookies are in the header.

Comment: So is it an app cookie or lb cookie? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-sticky-sessions.html did you create the policy?

Comment: I used the console to enable application stickiness, do I still need to create the policy through the tools?

Comment: But, I did add the policy, it still didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using **Application-Controlled** Session Affinity, the ELB will technically not decide the stickness based on your Application cookie, instead, it will assign it's own `AWSELB` cookie, similar to the duration based cookie, but following the same expiration date as your application cookie. So whenever the browser (or any other client) comes back to the ELB, it should send both Cookies and not only the Application one.

First, we need a regular `curl`, not sending cookies like you did with `--cookie "mychannelid=mytest"` but instead, saving the cookies received to a file called `cookies.txt`:

```
curl -c cookies.txt -v http://example.com/cookie.php
```

(note that `cookie.php` on the server needs to set the application cookie, for me, I called it `STICKINESSID` and set the value to `tomtest31mar1030`)

Curl output showing cookies being returned:

```
...
* Added cookie STICKINESSID="tomtest31mar1030" for domain example.com, path /, expire 1459525228
< Set-Cookie: STICKINESSID=tomtest31mar1030; expires=Fri, 01-Apr-2016 15:40:28 GMT
* Added cookie AWSELB="85937D8F08DC213046BA84053FDD6504FB203E36C25DA455A6835969F6D49F8DF9878D0F954A8EC75B8EE2AE208ECFE0AC2CE02E2EDE8DD014D2F17F4C80301EDBC4AE5CC3EBD730BD3127FF8DAAD636359B592B73" for domain example.com, path /, expire 1459525228
< Set-Cookie: AWSELB=85937D8F08DC213046BA84053FDD6504FB203E36C25DA455A6835969F6D49F8DF9878D0F954A8EC75B8EE2AE208ECFE0AC2CE02E2EDE8DD014D2F17F4C80301EDBC4AE5CC3EBD730BD3127FF8DAAD636359B592B73;PATH=/;EXPIRES=Fri, 01-Apr-2016 15:40:28 GMT
...
```

i.e. a file `cookies.txt` was created with both `STICKINESSID` and `AWSELB` cookies in it:

```
$ cat cookies.txt 

#  Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

example.com FALSE   /   FALSE   1459525228  STICKINESSID    tomtest31mar1030
example.com FALSE   /   FALSE   1459525228  AWSELB  85937D8F08DC213046BA84053FDD6504FB203E36C25DA455A6835969F6D49F8DF9878D0F954A8EC75B8EE2AE208ECFE0AC2CE02E2EDE8DD014D2F17F4C80301EDBC4AE5CC3EBD730BD3127FF8DAAD636359B592B73
```

Now, having the both cookies needed to keep the stickiness, let's test sending them in the request:

```
$ for i in {1..20}; do curl --silent -b cookies.txt http://example.com/cookie.php | grep Instance; done
Instance Id: <b>i-xxxxxxxx</b><br/>Zone: <b>eu-west-1b</b><br/>Internal IP: <b>10.0.0.21</b><br/>
Instance Id: <b>i-xxxxxxxx</b><br/>Zone: <b>eu-west-1b</b><br/>Internal IP: <b>10.0.0.21</b><br/>
Instance Id: <b>i-xxxxxxxx</b><br/>Zone: <b>eu-west-1b</b><br/>Internal IP: <b>10.0.0.21</b><br/>
Instance Id: <b>i-xxxxxxxx</b><br/>Zone: <b>eu-west-1b</b><br/>Internal IP: <b>10.0.0.21</b><br/>
Instance Id: <b>i-xxxxxxxx</b><br/>Zone: <b>eu-west-1b</b><br/>Internal IP: <b>10.0.0.21</b><br/>
Instance Id: <b>i-xxxxxxxx</b><br/>Zone: <b>eu-west-1b</b><br/>Internal IP: <b>10.0.0.21</b><br/>
Instance Id: <b>i-xxxxxxxx</b><br/>Zone: <b>eu-west-1b</b><br/>Internal IP: <b>10.0.0.21</b><br/>
...
```

(this assumes http://example.com/cookie.php outputs some debugging information where you can see the IP of the instance behind the ELB, so you can test the stickiness)

This shows, that stickiness is preserved across multiple requests. Try the same test without `-b cookies.txt` to test without stickiness.